# Wordpress Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted Won't upload images

Tags: image, wordpress, memory, php

Please can you help me. I've got this fatal error in WordPress. My site has been on for years and worked until a few days ago, This happened when I updated the network and my wordpress multi user install? It only does it on the main site, as it works fine on the sub sites.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4890018 bytes) in /home/artygirl/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 258

It can't be the memory limit as I fixed that ages ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the memory limit setting in `php.ini` e.g.

```
memory_limit = 128M ;
```

or add following line to your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahahha I think it was because they were png files!